# Fast Pandas column encoding

Tags: python, pandas

I've been trying to speed up the following code that encodes Pandas columns as ints.

```
with cpu_pool as p:
    results = p.amap(encode_int_column, jobs)
    while not results.ready():
        time.sleep(4)
    tmp_df = pd.DataFrame({k: v for k, v in results.get()})
```

with `encode_int_column` being

```
def encode_int_column(input_tuple: Tuple[str, Any]) -> Tuple[Any, List[int]]:
    uvals = np.unique(input_tuple[1])
    hmap = dict(zip(uvals, list(range(len(uvals)))))
    return input_tuple[0], [hmap[x] for x in input_tuple[1]]
```

Wondering what is a faster way of doing this (maybe more Pandas-idiomatic?). Thanks!

Comment: What's the type of cpu_pool?

Comment: Also, this looks like factorization, which you could probably speed up by calling this: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html

Comment: Thanks @NickODell will try that too, yes indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `return_inverse=True` as parameter of `np.unique`:

```
def encode_int_column(input_tuple: Tuple[str, Any]) -> Tuple[Any, List[int]]:
    _, enc = np.unique(input_tuple[1], return_inverse=True)
    return input_tuple[0], enc.tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Create a dictionary to store the mapping of unique values to integers
hmap = {}

# Iterate over the columns and encode them as integers
encoded_columns = {}
for col_name, col_values in jobs:
    if col_name not in hmap:
        unique_values = np.unique(col_values)
        encoded_values = pd.factorize(unique_values)[0]
        hmap[col_name] = dict(zip(unique_values, encoded_values))
    encoded_columns[col_name] = [hmap[col_name][x] for x in col_values]

# Create a DataFrame from the encoded columns
tmp_df = pd.DataFrame(encoded_columns)
```